# Plupload throws an error when trying to initiate

Tags: javascript, plupload

Using [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) v2 gets an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
```

Code example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
            browse_button: $('#chunked_file'),
            url: 'uploader.php'
        });

        uploader.init();
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of plain JavaScript when selecting `browse_button` DOM element solves the problem or simply selecting like `browse_button: 'chunked_file'`.

**Seems that plupload does not support jQuery as selector.**